# How to find an element by searching with InnerHTML using C# and Selenium

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, selenium

I want to get a particular element id by searching for a matching innerHTML string. For example I want to find the element id that has the innerHTML "Start of Car".

[image]

```
public static bool SelectSomething(IWebDriver driver, string searchName)
{
    var js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    if (js == null) return false;
    var element = (string) js.ExecuteScript("...script to get the ids...");
    var x = driver.FindElement(By.Id(element));
    x.Click();
    return true;
}
```

I know it is possible to loop through and find all of the innerHTML using JavaScript but how do you return the id once you find innerHTML that matches the 'searchName' string?

Comment: Why does a simple `.Text` not work?

Comment: I haven't considered that...where would .Text go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery it is simple, just use :contains - https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/5UvFE/

```
var found = $("td:contains('Start of Car')").attr('id');
```

This allows you to return the ID of the element in question.

Alternatively here is a way to do it with just JavaScript -

```
function textID(node, text) {
    if (node.nodeValue == text) {
        return node.parentNode;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var returnValue = textID(node.childNodes[i], text);
        if (returnValue != null) {
            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/5UvFE/1/